# How do I properly set these conditionals in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am VERY new to coding in general so this may come across as a stupid question.

Right now I am experimenting with conditional statements and trying to code a little decision based two-way path in the style of a text game, where the user is given two options and each option has a different outcome. Right now, the "if True" string is ALWAYS executed in the console, regardless of what the user types in. Why is this happening and how can I rewrite it to make the command happen correctly? Also, I thought I followed the instructions for pasting code here but it doesn't look quite right.

````
input ("Type 'left' if you want to go left and 'right' if you want to go right"

right = True 
left = False 

right = "right"
left = "left"

if True:
    print("You have been eaten by a monster. Game Over!") 
else:
    print("Congratulations you have made it to the castle!")
else:
    print("Error")```
````

Comment: You can not have two else branches in if statement. One of this should elif <statement>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your piece of code shows many misconceptions about variables, conditions, the general flow of the program... I would recommend that you find some tutorial and analyze some examples of code. SO is not a tutorial service and there are too many points to address in your question as it is. You're welcome to come back with more focused questions! And btw, you formatted your code perfectly in the question. ;)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - I'm sorry about that. I didn't mean to clutter the board and didn't know this was a bad question to ask here :/. I'll remove it

Comment: No problem!  And someone took the time to answer you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a stupid question!

In any programming language, when you come across an if-statement, you should read it as "if this statement evaluates to true, do this." So, in your example, writing

```py
if True:
    # do something
```

will always run that code, because True always evaluates to True!

It sounds like what you want to do is compare the player's input to some set string (in this case, "right" or "left"). The first thing you should know is that the `input()` function **returns, as a string, whatever the user input before hitting enter**. So, in this case, you might want to do something like

```py
direction = input("Would you like to go left or right?")
```

Now, once the user inputs something and hits enter, whatever they entered will be saved in the variable `direction`. Now, we can compare the entered string to whatever we want. In this example, we would want something like

```py
if direction == "left":
    # do left stuff
elif direction == "right":
    # do right stuff
else:
    # they didn't enter a valid string!
```

I hope this helps. If you're just starting out on your programming journey, I would recommend looking up some Python tutorials online which are specifically made for beginners, and try finding one that suits your learning style. Best of luck!